# calling the ajax call from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to put the ajax call in outside jsp and call it in the JS file .. here is my code

```js
deleteRow : function() {
  $("input:checkbox:checked").each(bindContext(function(index, item) {
   var str = $(item).attr("id");
   str = str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1);
   var id = this.data[str][this.columns[1]];

   $.ajax({
    url : '/Spring3HibernateApp1/deleteDep',
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
     "id" : id,
    },
    dataType : "json"
   });
```

So what if I want to just put the ajax call in function in another jsp ??

Comment: apart from surrounding it with `<script>` tags?

Comment: this deleteRow function in JS file .. i want just to call the ajax call from another file like jsp and call that function in stead of the ajax call in JS

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking: You're posting _some_ function and you want to call it from _somewhere_. What have you tried? What happened? What should happen instead?